# Laravel 5 Column it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I got an error in SQL when trying to join and group the id using Laravel.

> Column **'push_notifications.title'** is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an **aggregate** function or the **GROUP BY** clause

I've been trying to use Max and Min but I still got an error.

**Here's my code :**

```
$data  = $this->model->select( 'push_notifications.id', 'push_notifications.title', 'push_notifications.description', 'push_notifications.attachment', 'push_notifications.feature_id', 'push_notifications.target_id', 'features.title as feature', 'push_notifications.end_at')
            ->join('push_notification_users', 'push_notification_users.push_notification_id', '=', 'push_notifications.id')
            ->join('push_notification_roles', 'push_notification_roles.push_notification_id', '=', 'push_notifications.id')
            ->leftJoin('features', 'features.id', '=', 'push_notifications.feature_id')
            ->where( 'push_notifications.notif_target', 'homepage' )
            ->where(function($role) {
                $roles = RoleUser::where('user_id',$this->user->id)->first();
                $role->where( 'push_notification_roles.deleted_at', null )
                    ->where( 'push_notification_roles.role_id', $roles->role_id );
             })
            ->orWhere(function($user) {
                $user->where( 'push_notification_users.deleted_at', null )
                    ->where( 'push_notification_users.user_id', $this->user->id );
             })
            ->where( 'push_notifications.end_at', '>',  Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() )
            ->groupBy( 'push_notifications.id' )
            ->get();
```

If you have any solution just tell Me, I will really appreciate. Thank You

Comment: push_notifications.title column is not the part of GROUP BY, try adding this column.

Comment: I've been try add all column but still error

Answer (score 1):

'push_notifications.title' is not found. May there be some spelling mistake. Check thoroughly. If not so then please attach screenshot of your table structure i.e. push_notifications.

Also another reason is that there must be diff-diff values of push_notifications.title for 'push_notifications.id' and there can be multiple 'push_notifications.title' for single 'push_notifications.id' in groupBy. Only select 'push_notifications.id' and some other unique columns will work in your case.

refer this: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php